# CSS Centering is by top left of inner element

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm trying to center an inner element using CSS, and for some reason the inner element is centering based on the top left corner, rather than its center: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvxeEo

HTML:

```
<div class="topic">
<span class="title-box">hello!</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.topic {
 background-color: #84BACE;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  width:500px; 
  height:500px; 
 position: relative;
}

.title-box {
   background-color: #000; 
  color: #fff; 
  font-size: 60px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);"
}
```

Is there a way to set it so that it's properly centered? The inner element will be of unknown width/height, as it's dynamic text.

Thanks!

Comment: Your browser doesn't support `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`.

Comment: Ah, right you are... I tried it in Chrome and it worked. Bizarre, as I'm using Safari 8.05. So what's the best solution, if `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` doesn't work in some modern browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this — http://codepen.io/sergdenisov/pen/ZGOzrr:

```
.topic {
  background-color: #84BACE;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  width:500px; 
  height:500px; 
  position: relative;
}

.title-box {
  background-color: #000; 
  color: #fff; 
  font-size: 60px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Totally worked--thanks! So I just needed that extra bit of CSS for Safari in there. (Will accept this answer as soon as it allows me to.)

Comment: Thanks again, Sergey. I did accept... I was just blocked from accepting it for several minutes for some reason!

Answer (score 1):

[I made one simple change to your code here.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLjZQJ)
I hope this is what you were asking. The reason "hello" was centered in the blue instead of the page was that that span was inside the blue div. I simply moved the span outside of the div.

```
<div class="topic"></div>
<span class="title-box">hello!</span>
```